# Why do DatePart and DateName return different values for the same date?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to get the day number and name from a given date field.
But the results are confusing.
For example the following sql :

```
declare @date date = '20161018'

select datepart(dw, @date) as daynumber,
       datename(weekday, @date) as DayName,
       datename(weekday, 3) as DayNumber3,
       datename(weekday, 1) as DayNumber1
```

it produces this result :

```
daynumber   DayName     DayNumber3    DayNumber1    
3           Tuesday     Thursday      Tuesday
```

As you can see the datepart returns 3 and when I use this datepart in the call to datename it returns `Tuesday`.
But when I call datepart direct with the number 3 it returns `Thursday` and when I call datepart direct with the number 1 it returns `Tuesday`

So why does `datepart(dw, @date)` returns 3 in stead of 1 while `datename(weekday, @date)` does returns the correct day name ?

For me it is important to get the number 1 in stead of 3 and still keep getting Tuesday for this date.

**EDIT:**
The desired output I want for '20161018' is

```
daynumber    DayName
1            Tuesday
```

How can I get this result for the date from my example ?

Comment: The second parameter for `datename` is a DATE, so `3` is being converted to an actual date by SQL Server.

Comment: `datename(weekday, 3)` doesn't do what you think it does. It assumes that `3` is an actual date, (1900-01-04, since the dates in a datetime start in 1900-01-01), and that date is a thursday

Comment: OK thank you so how can I get the daynumber from the date field then ?

Comment: Do you mean `datepart(wk, @date)`?

Comment: you are doing that with the `datepart`?

Comment: So, you want to make tuesday the second day of the week?

Comment: @DavidG No I dont want the weeknumber I want to day of week number. For Tuesday that should be 1 on my sql server

Comment: @Lamak Yes I want to get the day of week number and monday is day 0 for me

Comment: then just set monday as the day 0 of the week first: `SET DATEFIRST 2`

Comment: @Lamak that is already the case but how can I get number 1 for this date  in stead of 3 ?

Comment: *sigh* did you try to run the code I posted first?, because that should give you the result you want

Comment: @Lamak you only posted code to set the day of week first, that is not my problem. In my sql server monday is already day 0

Comment: @Lamak I edited my question with desired outcome

Comment: @GuidoG no, it is not, because then you would get `1` as a result of the datepart for a tuesday. Run what I posted and then run `declare @date date = '20161018'

select datepart(dw, @date) as daynumber` and see the results. Don't just post comments without trying the code first

Comment: @Lamak OK you are right now it does works. But is this setting only for this statement ? Should  I repeat it every time ?

Comment: why the downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add 5 and mod 7 will get your results as below:

```
Declare @date date = '20161018'

Select (datepart(dw, @date) + 5) % 7 as daynumber,
   datename(weekday, @date) as DayName,
   datename(weekday, 3) as DayNumber3,
   datename(weekday, 1) as DayNumber1
```